# destruct json with error Property 'xxx' does not exist on type from a optional type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

what is the best practice to destruct a json object that is optional type from the other? I have the following code that `Child` interface is optional type from `Parent` and I have the error `Property 'name' does not exist on type 'Child | undefined'.(2339)`

```
interface Child {
    name: string,
    phone: number,
}
interface Parent {
    person?: Child
}
const variable: Parent[] = [{person: {name: 'google', phone: 456}}, {person: {name: 'amazon', phone: 1234}]

variable.map(({person}) => {
    const {name, phone} = person
})
```

Comment: Properties don’t exist on `undefined` (i.e., the value of a missing property), so you have to first check that it is not `undefined` before proceeding

Answer (score 0):

If you check if there is a `person` before deconstructing the variable, you can avoid the TypeScript error and related runtime errors. An example of this is returning early like the below.

```js
interface Child {
    name: string,
    phone: number,
}
interface Parent {
    person?: Child
}
const variable: Parent[] = [{person: {name: 'google', phone: 456}}, {person: {name: 'amazon', phone: 1234}}]

variable.map(({person}) => {
    // If there's no person, return nothing
    // (or whatever you'd like to do to handle this case)
    if (!person) return;
    const {name, phone} = person
})
```